# How to build react application (with multiple environments) that runs on Apache

Tags: reactjs, package.json

Typically deployment process: You build once

In Java or any other programming language, you build your application once and then deploy to various environments. There is like .env or .properties file which has environment configurations that are loaded when application starts.

How does react work

In react, from my understand there is package.json. So, it uses it to do build. OUr package.json has following content:

"price": "http://11.222.111.122/myApi/pricing",
    "teacher" : "http://11.222.111.122/myApi/teacher",
    "mainbanner" : "https://11.222.111.122/myApi/mainbanner",

We running build the application and run on Apache server (not on node.js)

Question:
a. How can we have environment file so that we can specify to use above urls at time of starting application. 
Obviously, we have different urls for different environment.

Comment: You mean to run multi projects live in the browser at the same time?

Comment: Not running projects in browser at same time.  We just want to build once and deploy to various servers

Answer (score 0):

Navigate into your React project folder using Terminal or CMD and build your React project using command:

```
npm run build
```

Then a build folder will be created inside your React project which will contain the final production files. Just upload those files into www or public folder of your Apache server.
If you want use it as subdomain, upload it to your subdomain folder.
Remember that React built version works like other Javascript web applications at the end.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of that approach. However, we have 15 servers (5 development, 5 for testing, 2 staging, 1 prod). This approach means i need to build 15 times. Also, there is risk as what i am deploying to staging servers is not identical to production.

Comment: I don't know about servers, but I know you don't have to build 15 times you just need to build one time and upload the same folder to all servers.